# Tag Wiki Editor Qualifications

Tags: discussion, tags

Why does the Tag Wiki for the GIS StackExchange require users to have a reputation of 1500 in order to make edits?  There are many tags that have no wiki entries, and lowering the reputation threshold would allow more users to contribute to those wikis.  Any mistakes made in those entries could always be corrected by other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a carryover from a generic site template.  It's 1,500 rep on Stack Overflow too, for example.

Remember it also requires being in the top 20 for that tag or a bronze tag badge.  The badge is 100 upvotes on non-CW answers (questions don't count) and at least 20 non-CW answers posted.  That's quite a lot for a single tag, and you're almost guaranteed to have 1,500 rep by the time you meet it.

It might not even be a good idea to quickly fill out tag wikis when a site is new and the exact use of certain tags is still being initially figured out by the community.  The "obvious" tags should already be obvious and less obvious tags may be interpreted differently by various users, or change names.

That said, if you want to contribute to a tag wiki *now,* why not write up a draft and post it here on meta?  Let other users contribute to (i.e. make it community-owned/wiki) and comment on that, and I bet a moderator would be happy to add it as an initial version in the tag wiki.

Comment: I definitly agree with the requirement that a user be in the top 20 before being able to edit a tag wiki, although this would not be difficult with most tags just because the total number of users is still relatively low. As far as the tag wiki being filled in when the site is new, there are advantages and disadvantages, but we should consider how helpful it would be for new users to have at least a basic entry in for most tags.

Comment: @Seth: I'm undecided on whether allowing widespread tag wiki editing early on is good or bad, but I did want to mention it.  Though if the entries you want are all really basic, that should be easier to draft up and less hassle/controversy for a moderator to apply.  (But I'm also unsure of the value in basic descriptions that should be more or less obvious from the tag name — that's how tags are useful in the first place.)

Comment: That's an excellent point.  The example that prompted me to write the question to begin with is the "Silverlight" tag.  I don't think it's the purpose of the tag wiki to explain what Silverlight is, someone could just look that up on Wikipedia if they didn't know.  I would like to give it a GIS context though and give examples of different applications for GIS in Silverlight.  But I may take up your idea and write up a draft for a moderator to apply.

Comment: @Seth: Well, I would link to Wikipedia in that tag wiki, just for convenience and clarity, but I certainly would like to see more information as a user. :)  I think we're on the same page here.