# Editing tag descriptions?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wikis

I just created a new tag for [hexagonal-grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid); there is a growing number of questions on this kind of grid or sampling system and no tag to gather them.

However, I can not find any mechanism to add a description to this tag. Is it something only available to moderators? Or is there some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click on the [hexagonal-grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-grid) tag you should reach the page below:

[image]

click on the [help us create it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3705) link and at your reputation you should be able to suggest edits to that tag's wiki and excerpt.

The [Approve Tag Wiki Edits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege only becomes available at a reputation of 5,000.

---

If you are unable to suggest the edit as I describe then please let us know because a 2010 Q&A here, [Tag Wiki Editor Qualifications](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/tag-wiki-editor-qualifications), indicates that it may need 1,500 reputation, but that is not listed on our [privileges page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Further research suggests that it was changed in 2011: [Has there been a change in the tag wiki editing privileges policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78807/has-there-been-a-change-in-the-tag-wiki-editing-privileges-policy)

Comment: The menu was not showing when I first filed the question. But now it is there and I am able to edit.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Perhaps there is caching involved.

Comment: I doubt. This is more likely something related to approval by moderators.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I am certain that there was no approval by a moderator involved until after you made your edit (which was when I approved your edit).  Looking at the history of the tag wiki it was created by the Community user an hour ago which was probably when I clicked the `help us create it` link but I am pretty sure that if you clicked that link the same would have happened.

Comment: As I said initially, the `help us create it` link was not visible when I filed this question. This might be a bug of some kind.